# Django - Unable to display an image from folder within media folder

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web, django-rest-framework

I am trying to load an image from a folder within 'media' folder (media/tshrirts) onto template using django. Below is my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
**I tried both the roots none of them work.
```

Below is my models.py

```
 from django.db import models
 # Create your models here.
class tshirts(models.Model):
    brand=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='tshirts/')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**this is part of the tshirts.html** Why image.url is none??

```
<div class='tshirts'>
        {% for eachtshirt in alltshirts %}
        <div class='tshirt'>
            <a href="#">{{eachtshirt.brand}}</a>
            <p>{{eachtshirt.name}}</p>
            <p>{{eachtshirt.price}}</p>
            <img src="{{eachshirt.image.url}}"/>
            {% if eachshirt.image.url == None %}
            <p>{{"Image Not Found"}}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

finally, urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
.
.
.
    url(r'^tshirts/',include('tshirts.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

After I uploaded the image as an admin and clicked the link, the image was properly displayed.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/tshirts/t-shirt2.jpg - the image was displayed here.
How can I fix this, please let me know thanks!!!
[Screenshot for the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fPUV.png)

Answer (score 1):

The root of your media, should include the `BASE_DIR`, like the following:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

You have a typo in your template, you'are accessing `{{eachshirt.image.url}}` without `t`. the correct is

```
{{eachtshirt.image.url}} <!-- with t : each tshirt -->
```

Comment: did you try uploading another, don't test your old pictures, the path of old pics might be corrupted

Comment: Yes. I deleted the old ones and loaded new images.

Comment: OMG.......I was on this for 5 hours. Thank you so much. It is working!!

Comment: Glad to be of help!